# Erro ao acessar end-point utilizando restsharp

Tags: vb.net, restsharp

Tenho um uma API (.NET Framework 4.8) que se comunica com outra camada (.NET Framework 4.0) onde tenho desenvolvido um método o qual persiste uma informação no banco de dados, e ao final aciona OUTRA API (de terceiro) para enviar um e-mail.
Quando rodo a aplicação em Windows 10 funciona normalmente, mas ao tentar rodar no Windows 7 (na IDE) e no Windows 2012 (publicado) o response me retornar status code 0 com o seguinte erro "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

Codificação que estou usando para fazer a chamada no end-point:

```vb
Dim request As New RestRequest(endpoint, type)

request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
request.AddHeader("sourceToken", _sourceToken)

If Not IsNothing(body) Then request.AddJsonBody(body)
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12
```

Answer (score -3):

Tive um problema parecido envolvendo versões diferentes de windows e o que me ajudou foi adicionar essa linha:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

Mas seu problema pode ser por conta do **AddHeader**. Recomenda-se utilizar **IRestClient.UserAgent** no lugar, segundo [documentação do RestSharp](https://restsharp.dev/get-help/faq.html#connection-closed-with-ssl)